How to set state management only to one tab with PersisentBottomNavBar?
I am  using PersisentBottomNavBar2 and there is parameter stateManagement which is basically PageView with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
My case is that I want to preserve state only of one tab. I tried to remove code responsible for keeping page alive from package code and implement it by myself but it didn't work.
Is there any possible workaround to do something like this?
PersistentTabView(
        controller: pageController,
        navBarHeight: 70,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: false,
        stateManagement: true,
        selectedTabContext: (context) => selectedTabContext = context,
        navBarBuilder: (navBarConfig) => Style4BottomNavBar(
          navBarConfig: navBarConfig,
          navBarDecoration: const NavBarDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                      color: Color(0xFFD1D5DB)
                  )
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 8,
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                    blurRadius: 6,
                    spreadRadius: -2
                )
              ]
          ),
        ),
        onTabChanged: (index) {
          context.read<NavigationCubit>().updateMainNavigator(true);
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },

